# How to convert date/time field to a text field using formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have 3 fields on UI
Name field1, date time field2, text field3

field3 is a formula field which is concatenation of field1 and field2.

```
field1 + text(field2)
```

if field1 value is Sam D
field2 value is 5/17/2022, 12:00 PM
field3 is being populated as Sam D, 2022-05-17 19:00:00Z

but the expected value is Sam D, 2022-05-17 12:00 PM

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] then [edit] your question to demonstrate what you've tried and where you are stuck. There's a community expectation that you have already tried to solve the problem for yourself and that you can explain where you are at and what isn't working for you. In this specific case, you will find plenty of documentation around date/time values, time zones and Salesforce formulae by simply googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below logic for the Date time field.

```
LEFT(TEXT( field2 ), 10) + ' ' + 
TEXT(IF(
  OR(
    VALUE( MID( TEXT( field2 ), 12, 2 ) ) = 0,
    VALUE( MID( TEXT( field2 ), 12, 2 ) ) = 12
  ),
  12,
  VALUE( MID( TEXT( field2 ), 12, 2 ) ) 
   - 
   IF( 
     VALUE( MID( TEXT( field2 ), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 
     0, 
     12 
   )
)) + ':' +
MID( TEXT( field2 ), 15, 2 ) + ' ' +
IF(
  VALUE( MID( TEXT( field2 ), 12, 2 ) ) < 12,
  "AM",
  "PM"
)
```

---

For additional details you can go through [Sample Date Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm)